# The universe block encompasses all Go source text

Tags: c, go

Spec mentions: "universe block encompasses all Go source text"

All code is lexically scoped to the universe block.

Go source text is in `/usr/local/go/src/` folder in local setup

```
src$
src$
src$ pwd
/usr/local/go/src
src$ 
src$ ls
all.bash  arena           builtin     clean.rc  container  debug     expvar  go.mod  image     log        make.rc  os         race.bat       run.bash  sort     syscall   time
all.bat   bootstrap.bash  bytes       cmd       context    embed     flag    go.sum  index     make.bash  math     path       README.vendor  run.bat   strconv  testdata  unicode
all.rc    bufio           clean.bash  cmp.bash  crypto     encoding  fmt     hash    internal  make.bat   mime     plugin     reflect        run.rc    strings  testing   unsafe
archive   buildall.bash   clean.bat   compress  database   errors    go      html    io        Make.dist  net      race.bash  regexp         runtime   sync     text      vendor
src$ 
src$ go version
go version go1.20.2 linux/amd64
src$ 
src$
```

---

1. Does the universe block encompass the source in `/usr/local/go/src`? that gets linked at build time(`go build`)
2. if yes, does `go build` generate binary from source code( that is statically linked)? In C world, we have options to link code at build time and runtime(dynamically using `dlopen()` api)

Answer (score 2):

1. Yes, all package blocks are nested within the universe block. That includes packages included with the Go distribution.
2. Yes, the `go build` command translates Go source code to binary format.  Go code is typically statically linked.

(The universe block is unrelated to questions of static linking, dynamic linking, etc.)

Answer (score 2):

Universal block is the scope that is visible from any location in your application. It contains [the following global symbols](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Predeclared_identifiers):

```
Types:
    any bool byte comparable
    complex64 complex128 error float32 float64
    int int8 int16 int32 int64 rune string
    uint uint8 uint16 uint32 uint64 uintptr

Constants:
    true false iota

Zero value:
    nil

Functions:
    append cap clear close complex copy delete imag len
    make max min new panic print println real recover
```

Thanks to the universal blocks those symbols needn't be imported and they are ready to use in each and every file of the source code.

Yes, Golang is source-code language. The application is statically linked, and the compiler also processes source code files from the installed distribution (e.g. `/usr/local/go/src`). But No, this is not due to the universal block.

The files in `/usr/local/go/src` are aggregated into modules (such as `runtime`, `fmt`, `encoding`, etc.) and the compiler is pre-configured to pull the sources for those standard modules from `/usr/local/go/src`.

Once upon a time there were binary-only packages that did resemble static libraries. But they were [dropped a few years ago](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/28152). Still there is a feature called [`plugin`](https://pkg.go.dev/plugin) with dynamic loading, but using them is the easiest way to shoot yourself in the foot.

So, yes, Golang is source-only language, and `go build` compiles all sources including the standard library. To save time on consecutive build the tool keeps compiled objects in `go env GOCACHE` directory.